# Linux Completely Fair Scheduler and sched_latency_ns

Tags: linux, scheduling, latency

I thought I understood CFS but...

The scheduled latency is the time that in which every runnable process can expect to get a share of the processor. In the Linux Kernel code it gives:

(default: 6ms * (1 + ilog(ncpus)), units: nanoseconds)

Which for a 1 cpu machine gives 6ms and for a 4 core machine 18ms.
I checked this out on a Rpi Zero one core and a Rpi 4 four cores and 
it seems to be the case. 
However the Pi 4 with four cores is a more powerful machine than the Zero surely you would expect the schedule latency to be smaller not three times bigger?
Looking at sched_min_granularity in both cases they both handle 8 tasks before falling back to a fixed time slice of 0.75ms and 2.25 ms. 
I am clearly cross wired on this ...

Answer (score 2):

> *surely you would expect the schedule latency to be smaller not three times bigger*

And that is the reason why it gets "corrected" with _NONE, _LOG. or _LINEAR.

The concept of SMP also works when you look at it as **splitting**, and not adding, a CPU. Then you don't gain performance overall, but still have better responsiveness.

This short function ("period") uses both *min_granularity* and *latency*. I reformatted a bit. I don't think you have to know anything about C language to understand - there is even an *unlikely* hint:

```
static u64 __sched_period(unsigned long nr_running)
{
    if (unlikely(nr_running > sched_nr_latency))

        return   nr_running * sysctl_sched_min_granularity;
    else
        return                sysctl_sched_latency;
}
```

In the end it is more about the word than the thing: wikipedia, CFS:

> ...the **atomic units** by which an individual process' share of the
>   CPU was allocated (thus making redundant the **previous notion of
>   timeslices**)

---

That **redundant** word is still in `kernel/sched/fair.c`:

```
 * (to see the precise effective timeslice length of your workload,
 *  run vmstat and monitor the context-switches (cs) field)
```

---

The values **6ms**, **0.75ms** (=1/8) and **24ms** (= _LOG-corrected for ncpus=8) *can* be IMHO interpreted as periods i.e. timeslices. If you convert it to Hertz, it matches with the `Kconfig.hz` ranges, which are 100HZ (server) to 1000HZ (high-responsiveness).

```
1/.00075 s
1333.3 Hz
```

More than thousand min-granularity-"slices" fit in a second.

```
1/.006 s
166.6 Hz
```

166 uncorrected latency "slices" lies between the 100HZ "server" and the 250HZ "compromise".

```
1/.024 s
41.6 Hz
```

With log-correction for 8 cores, each one can reduce context switching by factor 4, still the "effective latency" remains low.

---

Compare it to a barber shop, where you want to guarantee that no new costumer has to wait longer than 10 minutes. This means you have to *preempt* your current costumer in the seat every 10 minutes. at least for the time it takes to say hello.

A shop with four seats and barbers can reduce that 10-minute slice. With four barbers working each in a cabinet, they only have to stop and peek every 40 minutes, and on average a newly entered costumer will only wait 10 min as before.

That would be the full, "linear" correction of latency: **multiply by N**.

But in the worst case, all four check for new costumers at the same time - because they started simultaneously. If a costumer enters one minute after that, he might have to wait 39 minutes before he gets served.

So as a compromise you multiply not by N, but **by log(N)**.

`1 + ilog(N)`

this gives 1+ilog(4) = 1+2, so the 4 barbers can extend their slice from 10 to 30 minutes (instead of 40). Together they achieve a 10-minute latency.

Quadruple to 16 and it extends only to 50 minutes. The "correction" is logarithmic and has this `+ 1`.

Comment: I have been trying to understand your answer for some days and I fall at the first point. What is log-correction. I have googled and read the code and I still don't understand what it does or why it is involved at all. Perhaps I'm searching for the wrong things and perhaps there is a document that I'm missing but I'm still confused.